# Ion using HTTPS

Tags: android, https, android-ion

I'm using Ion but when i try to use it with Https it gives me an exception.

Code:

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(mBaseUrl + "Token")
    .setJsonObjectBody(json)
    (...)
```

Exception:

```
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SourceFile:421)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:383)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper$4.onDataAvailable(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:172)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.BufferedDataEmitter.onDataAvailable(BufferedDataEmitter.java:33)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.BufferedDataEmitter.onDataAvailable(BufferedDataEmitter.java:61)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:20)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncNetworkSocket.onReadable(AsyncNetworkSocket.java:175)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:766)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:608)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:37)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:557)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:192)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(SourceFile:158)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.verifyCertificateChain(SourceFile:629)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake_bio(Native Method)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SourceFile:411)
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ ... 10 more
09-24 11:53:00.211  17654-17940/com.gfi.connectelu W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a recent reported [issue about SSL Handshake](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/386) on Ion:

Meanwhile, you could maybe take a look at [Ion: add support for self signed certificates](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/3)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking to a server with a bad certificate. If it's a self signed certificate, you need to install that in your ion's http client.

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```